# Update installment price on product configuration change Product Page Magento2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, product-page

I created a template to display the installment price of the product, on the product page.
I need to update this price when the user clicks the configurable product option.

Any help is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: I created a preference for "Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" to create a new price_type_code but debugging the product page does not pass through the getJsonConfig method.

I also created a preference for "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options" and debugging the product page also does not go through _getPriceConfiguration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating a preference for Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Configurable

Thanks